# Does the YLT translate Daniel 9:26 accurately?

Tags: translation-philosophy, prophecy, daniel, eschatology

Young's Literal Traslation

> 26 And after the sixty and two weeks, cut off is Messiah, and the city and the holy place are not his, ***the Leader who hath come doth destroy the people***; and its end [is] with a flood, and till the end [is] war, determined [are] desolations.

Daniel 9:26 New American Standard Bible (NASB)

> 26 Then after the sixty-two weeks the [a]Messiah will be cut off and have [b]nothing, and the people of the prince who is to come will destroy the city and the sanctuary. And [c]its end will come with a flood; even to the end [d]there will be war; desolations are determined.

Daniel 9:26 NASB

> 26 And after threescore and two weeks shall Messiah be cut off, but not for himself:  and the people of the prince that shall come shall destroy the city and the sanctuary;  and the end thereof shall be with a flood, and unto the end of the war desolations are determined.

The YLT translation of the above text is a little bit confusing,its as if the leader will actually destroy the people rather than the city and sanctuary.

How to understand the above text?

Answer (score 1):

I got here a few other versions of Daniel 9:26:

> (AKJV) And after three score and two weeks shall Messiah be cut off, but not for himself: and the people of the prince that shall come shall destroy the city and the sanctuary; and the end thereof shall be with a flood, and to the end of the war desolations are determined.
>
> (ASV) And after the threescore and two weeks shall the anointed one be cut off, and noteshall have nothing: and the people of the prince that shall come shall destroy the city and the sanctuary; and the end thereof shall be with a flood, and even unto the end shall be war; desolations are determined.
>
> (BBE) And at the end of the times, even after the sixty-two weeks, one on whom the holy oil has been put will be cut off and have no...;and the town and the holy place will be made waste together with a prince; and the end will come with an overflowing of waters, and even to the end there will be war; the making waste which has been fixed.
>
> (Darby) And after the sixty-two weeks shall Messiah be cut off, and shall have nothing; and the people of the prince that shall come shall destroy the city and the sanctuary; and the end thereof shall be with an overflow, and unto the end, war, --the desolations determined.
>
> (DRC) And after sixty-two weeks Christ shall be slain: and the people that shall deny him shall not be his. And a people with their leader that shall come, shall destroy the city and the sanctuary: and the end thereof shall be waste, and after the end of the war the appointed desolation.
>
> (EasyEnglish) After the 434 years, people will kill the special ruler that God has sent. He will have nothing. Then a foreign ruler will come with his army and he will destroy the city and the *holy place. The end will be like a fast river. War will continue until the end of that time. God has said that people would destroy things.
>
> (ISV) Then after the 62 weeks, the anointed one will be cut down (but not for himself). Then the people of the Coming Commander will destroy both the city and the Sanctuary. Its ending will come like a flood, and until the end there will be war, with desolations having been decreed.
>
> (KJV) And after H310 threescore H8346 and two H8147 weeks H7620 shall Messiah H4899 be cut off H3772, but not for himself: and the people H5971 of the prince H5057 that shall come H935 shall destroy H7843 the city H5892 and the sanctuary H6944; and the end H7093 thereof shall be with a flood H7858, and unto the end H7093 of the war H4421 desolations H8074 are determined H2782. note note
>
> (KJVLite) And after threescore and two weeks shall Messiah be cut off, but not for himself: and the people of the prince that shall come shall destroy the city and the sanctuary; and the end thereof shall be with a flood, and unto the end of the war desolations are determined. note note
>
> (MKJV1962) And after sixty-two weeks Messiah shall be cut off, but not [for] Himself. And the people of the ruler who shall come shall destroy the city and the sanctuary. And the end of it [shall be with the flood, and ruins are determined, until [the] end [shall be] war.
>
> (NET) Now after the sixty-two weeks, an anointed one will be cut off and have nothing. As for the city and the sanctuary, the people of the coming prince will destroy them. But his end will come speedily like a flood. Until the end of the war that has been decreed there will be destruction.
>
> (NHEB) After the sixty-two weeks an anointed one shall be cut off, and shall have nothing: and the people of the prince who shall come shall destroy the city and the sanctuary; and his end shall come with a flood, and until the end there shall be war; desolations are decreed.
>
> (WEB) After the sixty-two weeks the Anointed One note will be cut off, and will have nothing. The people of the prince who come will destroy the city and the sanctuary. Its end will be with a flood, and war will be even to the end. Desolations are determined.
>
> (Wycliffe) And after two and sixti woukis of yeeris Crist schal be slayn. And it schal not be his puple, that schal denye hym. And the puple with the duyk to comynge schal distrie the citee, and the seyntuarie; and the ende therof schal be distriyng, and after the ende of batel schal be ordeynede desolacioun.
>
> (Wycliffe-Modern) And after two and sixty weeks of years Christ shall be slain. And it shall not be his people, that shall deny him. And the people with the duke to coming shall destroy the city, and the saintuary; and the end thereof shall be destroying, and after the end of battle shall be ordained desolation.
>
> (YLT) And after the sixty and two weeks, cut off is Messiah, and the city and the holy place are not his, the Leader who hath come doth destroy the people; and its end is with a flood, and till the end is war, determined are desolations.

The Hebrew word used was translated to a CITY or TOWN,

> H5892
> Original: עיר ער עיר
> Transliteration: ‛ı̂yr ‛âr ‛âyar
> Phonetic: eer
>
> Strong's Definition: From H5782 a city (a place guarded by waking or a watch) in the widest sense (even of a mere encampment or post): - Ai [from margin], city, court [from margin], town.

I think the way the words were place in YLT made it look like "the people" are the ones who will be destroyed but if you read carefully, you will see that the context is the same as with the other translations.

In YLT, "the city and the holy place" was placed before "the leader and his people"  whereas in the other translations it was the other way. It was the lack of punctuation and the grammar that changed its meaning.

The "cut off is Messiah" seems confusing to me and its no wonder "the Leader who hath come doth destroy the people" has the same effect.

> Daniel 9:26 YLT And after the sixty and two weeks, cut off is Messiah, and the city and the holy place are not his, the Leader who hath come doth destroy the people; and its end is with a flood, and till the end is war, determined are desolations.

In my understanding of the verse, it is "the people" together with the Ruler/Leader who will destroy the city and the sanctuary.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hebrew grammar generally starts a sentence with a verb, and the original rendering has no punctuation or vowel points.

Comment: Hello richard, welcome to BHSE, glad to have you with us. If you haven't already, please make sure to take our tour, to see how we are a little different from other sites you may know. Thanks! (hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour)